# combinatorial ergodicity and promotion

Tags: ergodic-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

According to J. Propp, T. Roby, and (I believe) others, a cyclic action on a finite set $S$ given by a bijection $\zeta: S \longrightarrow S$ is said to be  ${\it ergodic}$ with respect to a statistic $\phi: S \longrightarrow \Bbb{N}$ if the average of $\phi$ on each orbit of the cyclic action equals the average of $\phi$ over all of $S$. There are a number of examples of this kind of behaviour when $S$ is taken to be the set of all linear extensions of a finite poset $P$ and $\zeta$ is Schützenberger's ${\it promotion}$ operator --- an interesting case among these examples occurs when $P$ is the poset associated to a Young diagram and $\phi$ is any of the usual suspects (e.g. counting inversions in tableau). Forgive me if I'm a bit glib here.

Consider now a finite poset $P$ (with a unique minimal element $\perp$ for simplicity) and a directed spanning tree $T$ of $P$, which itself may be viewed as a poset. Let $S$ be the set of all linear extensions of $T$ and let $\zeta$ be
the promotion operator. Clearly any linear extension of $P$ is also a linear extension of $T$ and so given a linear extension $s$ of $T$ we may declare $\phi(s)$ to be the number of linear extensions in its promotion orbit that are simultaneously linear extensions of $P$ as well. 
Under what circumstances will the promotion action with this choice of statistic be ergotic ?

regards,
A. Leverkuhn

Comment: Have you tried some examples ?